# How can I rename sheet in a different spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have copied multiple sheets from one spreadsheet to another using the `copyTo(spreadsheet)` method. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) suggests,

```
The copied sheet will be named "Copy of [original name]".
```

How can I rename that sheet, which is now effectively located in a different spreadsheet than the one hosting my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this can be done with a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname) when making the copy but I don't believe this is possible with just a copy of a sheet (with a single call).

I think you'll need to get it by the 'Copy of' name and use [setName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename).

Comment: You are probably right. A working solution I arrived at is to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId).getSheets();` to get the sheets in the new spreadsheet; then just loop over them and rename. A bit clumsy, but seems to work.